# How to incorporate upper case as well as lower case while processing a .csv file using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using Pandas to process a bunch of .csv files that have the column names John, Jake and Jeffrey.

Most of the files have the column names as **John**, **Jake** and **Jeffrey** so I didn't really have a problem.

Then I find that a bunch of files scattered around the folder have occurrences of **john** or **JOHN** (applies to Jake and Jeffrey too).

How can I make cases include this?

Comment: A straightforward way to do this is to uniformly work in a single case, forcing every name encountered to lowercase with `name.lower()` before doing any further processing with `name`.

Comment: Use titlecase instead

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you read in your data similarly to the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('some.csv')
```

You can use the `.title()` method of a string to change its case to title case.
This would change the case of `'JOHN'` to `'John'`. Given that your `pd.DataFrame` is called `df`, you can do the following for all of your CSVs:

```
df.columns = [col.title() for col in df.columns]
```

Pandas also provides access to `str` methods, like so:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.title()
```